Standard Naming Convention for Cadence Files
This is a question regarding the naming of libraries and cellviews in the Cadence Design Systems' IC tool. While being somewhat company and work-culture dependent, I am wondering what naming convention is the most popular one and the benefits it offers. As an example, I used to name my files with numeric preambles such as "0_amp" or "1_driver". Later I tried removing the numerals and simply using elaborate names such as "amp_ind_peak_2_V". Neither convention proved superior and both ended up being okay for small designs. However, I would like to know how others, especially companies with many shared IPs, etc., handle the naming of their files. That being said, inputs from academia and industry are welcome and appreciated alike!
